# How to teleop PR2 on ROS Hydro?

Tags: ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I install sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-pr2-* successfully.

I found that [pr2_teleop](http://wiki.ros.org/pr2_teleop) is suitable for groovy...

Where can I find teleop package for Hydro?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/182477/how-to-teleop-pr2-on-ros-hydro?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2014-07-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Sam,

I believe the teleop PR2 has been catkinized but not released yet for Hydro. If you wish to install from source and alpha test please use this link to get the source:

http://github.com/PR2/pr2_apps/

and be sure to

```
git checkout -b hydro-devel
```

after you have git cloned :)

---

Originally posted by [DevonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/4255/devonw/) with karma: 644 on 2014-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0